# Azure Virtual Machine Billing

Tags: azure, billing, azure-virtual-machine

I dont know if this is the right place, but I am assuming MSFT staff also answers these questions since the azure portal links to StackOverflow?

Questions:

- I understand that Azure no longer bills me for a VM so long as it and its cloud service are stopped.  But what is unclear is am I going to be billed for the Cloud Service itself?  For example say i create a Virtual machine and by doing so i get a cloud service for it (with ip).  Then I turn off that virtual Machine and the cloud service.  Do i still get billed for the cloud service even though everything is turned off?
- Continuing on the question above.  Do i get billed storage fees for the Virtual Machines filesystem.  Currently windows vms are around 120GB in size.   How does the billing work out for virtual machines?  And how does it change if the machine is turned off.
- How are Custom Images billed?  Say i create my Windows 2012 Master image with IIS and a few other components installed.  Then I create my own Image so that I can bring up vms more rapidly.  Where is the VM image stored?  Will it be in my blob container under VHD's?  And again will microsoft charge me to store this image?  Will it be the full 120+ GB or the actual size of the image stored.

Sorry to ask these questions.  Tried my best to google around and all i could find was a post by Scott Gu where he stated VMs wont be billed and very little detail beyond that.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site about programming related questions, for software billing related questions, a different site should be used.  I suggest checking these out here: http://stackexchange.com/sites# I think superuser.com would be the best match.

Comment: I agree, I found a few other billing questions here.  I just am not clear if MSFT and StackOverflow have some sort of relationship where MSFT support is also here to answer questions.  Regardless it would be good to have here, because the Azure forums are a total mess.

Comment: Although there likely are many people from Microsoft who maintain this site with high reputations, the two companies are completely unrelated.  If Microsoft can't get their billing price sheet into a format that is understandable, this is not the place for that Marketing department to discover the error of their ways.  Please delete this question and the down votes will not count against you.

Comment: I voted up your comment because I agree MSFT needs to do a better job in their pricing sheets. The calculator could also be done to count for MSDN subscriptions.  I have a few VMs running to see if i can answer my own question by looking at my bill.  In the meanwhile I am going to leave the question open because I think its helpful to others, specially coming from AWS where pricing is pretty transparent and the forums are full of useful answers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I understand that Azure no longer bills me for a VM so long as it and
>   its cloud service are stopped. But what is unclear is am I going to be
>   billed for the Cloud Service itself? For example say i create a
>   Virtual machine and by doing so i get a cloud service for it (with
>   ip). Then I turn off that virtual Machine and the cloud service. Do i
>   still get billed for the cloud service even though everything is
>   turned off?

Essentially think of a `cloud service` as a shell under which you deploy a VM. Among other things, a cloud service provides you with a DNS (yourcloudservice.cloudapp.net for example). What you get charged for is the VM and not the cloud service so if you have nothing deployed in a cloud service, you don't get charged anything.

> Continuing on the question above. Do i get billed storage fees for the
>   Virtual Machines filesystem. Currently windows vms are around 120GB in
>   size. How does the billing work out for virtual machines? And how does
>   it change if the machine is turned off.

Yes, I believe so. You would be charged for 120 GB of storage (based on this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_shep/archive/2013/06/10/azure-billing-per-minute-and-no-compute-charge-for-a-stopped-iaas-vm.aspx) [See my note on pricing below].

> How are Custom Images billed? Say i create my Windows 2012 Master
>   image with IIS and a few other components installed. Then I create my
>   own Image so that I can bring up vms more rapidly. Where is the VM
>   image stored? Will it be in my blob container under VHD's? And again
>   will microsoft charge me to store this image? Will it be the full 120+
>   GB or the actual size of the image stored.

Custom images are billed in a similar way as standard images as in both cases the VHD file is stored in your blob storage account so Microsoft will charge you for storage. Since VHDs are essentially saved as page blobs and page blobs are only charged based on the bytes occupied you will only be charged for the space you consumed.

**UPDATE**

**VHD Pricing**: Essentially VHDs are stored in blob storage as page blobs and the pricing of page blobs is calculated a little bit differently. For page blobs, you're only charged for the bytes you used instead of total blob size. So for example, you have a VHD of 120 GB size (i.e. your page blob size is 120 GB) but you're only occupying 30 GB there, you're only charged for 30 GB and not 120 GB.

Comment: Guarav, Thank you for taking the time to answer this question.  Can you edit your answer to reference David's comments around VHD size and storage fees so that I can mark  your answer? I just want to make sure if anyone else looks at this thread they will not miss his comments as well.  (Wish i could choose both answers as they make sense)

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri could you please suggest me if i stop my cloud service then I will not be billed for stopped cloud service? 
VMs:- When I am looking into portals portals showing Virtual machine 0.
Databases:- Azure bills me for databases too? As I have two unused databases too.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri All what I need I have one additional cloud service that I am using for testing purpose. So I dont want charges for this all time. I want to pay only for that time of span When I need to test something on this service. Please help

Comment: @KulbirSingh For Cloud Services, if you want to stop billing then you **must** delete the deployment (no need to delete the cloud service though). Stopping the cloud service will still cost you money.HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks very much bro. I have deleted the deployments from both staging and production environment of my cloud service without deleting my cloud service.

Answer (score 5):

As @Gaurav stated, you're not charged for the service container, only for running vm's. In the case of stopped VM's, you won't be charged, although you lose your assigned IP address if you have no other running vm's. *You can choose to keep a vm provisioned to preserve IP address but then you'll continue paying for the VM*. When a VM is stopped, you'll still pay for its storage (since these are *persistent* virtual machines).

Regarding storage costs: While the vhd might be a 120GB disk, you only pay for storage that's been actually used. That is, the *page blob* uses sparse allocation. If you format a 120GB volume but only use 30gb, you're billed for 30gb monthly, not 120gb. You pay for all vhd's, including your custom images, since each is stored in your storage account. Again, you don't pay for 120gb on your custom images; just for the allocated pages.

Comment: Thank you a million for the clarification.  Both you and @Guarav have really clarified things for me.  I have one more small question and rather than ask it in a seperate question you may know the answer.  What are the port speeds for different size VMs?  Before when we tried Azure VM role (last year) microsoft published the port speeds.  Now they are nowhere to be found.  Are all the port speeds now at full speed regardless of vm size?  Or does microsoft give you a port speed based on your total account size (number of vms/services).  Or is it number of vms running in a service?

Comment: But deleting files inside a VM doesn’t free pages, does it? Or does NTFS zero out pages and the blob service consider zeroed pages unused?

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you get charged for the OS disk. If you have a data disk then you will be charged for the space used.

Comment: You do get charged for the OS or data disk